# MediaWiki - how do I create a page which auto populates a link from the current page?

Tags: mediawiki

Hi sorry if this a daft question (newbie), I am currently using mediawiki-1.23.1 and have been looking for a way in which to create it easy for an end user to create a page. However I would love to be able to have a link auto-created/auto populate on the current page. I currently use the InputBox extension. But it doesn't seem to allow this additional function from my research. Is this a possibility through extensions, or will this have to be done via a custom php template?

current InputBox details.

```
<inputbox>
type=create
width=24
break=no
buttonlabel=Create new page
</inputbox>
```

Any help or direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Workaround: Use a template for the new page that contains a category, and show the contents of that category on the current page.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I will try your recommendation. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately - that wasn't an option for the end users. So backing up here: All i want to do is the following -- Say user is on page A. They want to click on an input button to create a new page. So they type new page in the input box and click on "create new page icon" Then it goes to the new page "B" so they can input data etc. However back on page "A" a link to page B is now present. Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create a link from page A to page B automatically if you don't "mark" something on page B. And the simplest thing you can mark is "[[Category:...]]", like Bergi said. I will use preloaded text to make it easier.

### What you need

If you want page in main namespace to be the page where end users type in InputBox, you need any extension that will show content of category page such as *Extension:CategoryTree*, or *Extension:Dynamic Page List* (see also [Transclude a category in MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050853/transclude-a-category-in-mediawiki)).

### Steps

#### On page [[Template:PreloadedText]]

Put the following content

```
<!-- Do not edit under this line -->
<includeonly>[[Category:CreatedFromPageA]]</includeonly>
```

#### On page [[A]]

Put the following content

```
<!-- Show all pages in [[Category:CreatedFromPageA]] -->
<!-- Assuming you use Extension:CategoryTree -->
<categorytree hideroot="true" namespaces="-">CreatedFromPageA</categorytree>

<!-- InputBox -->
<inputbox>
type=create
width=24
break=no
buttonlabel=Create new page
preload=Template:PreloadedText
</inputbox>
```

### For end users

On page [[A]], they will see every page that was created via the InputBox at the top. At the bottom, they will see the InputBox. After typing pagename and clicking the button, they will be brought to the page they typed. There will be the following text existing already

```
<!-- Do not edit under this line -->
[[Category:CreatedFromPageA]]
```

As long as they don't bother with these lines, after they click save, the new page will appear on the list automatically.