# Is it possible to use the "Pages in category..." list in mediawiki in a template without an extension?

Tags: categories, mediawiki

I would like to use a category page as a template to show the "Pages in category..." on another page, but when I attempt to template the category page it only shows the details written on the category page itself. Not the list of pages in the category.

Is there any way to access this "Pages in category..." section outside of the category page itself?

For example, on a DnD wiki there is a category of type of spell in a class. Each of the spell pages for Druids is created and each of those spell pages has the Druid_Spells category. Then, the Category:Druid_Spells page has a text and some details added onto it.

I'm attempting to make a separate Druid page that has details about the class, but I don't want to manually edit and maintain the list of Druid spells. I would like to be able to pass the list of druid spells from the category onto the Druid page and as druid spells are added or changed the category would handle updating the list for me.

However, when I add this to the Druid page:

```
= Druid Spells =
{{:Category:Druid_Spells}}
```

It is only passing the text of the Druid_Spells category page. It isn't showing the "Pages in category Druid_Spells..." and listing all of them alphabetically like the category page itself does.

I would prefer not having to use the Druid spells category page itself because I would like to tie other category pages into the main Druid page, like skills and abilities.

[Transclude a category in MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050853/transclude-a-category-in-mediawiki) is a similar question, but all of the answers are extensions. Is this possible without an extension?

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit for [webmasters.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not involve programming or tools primarily used in a programming environment.

Comment: @miken32 I would argue that the Wikitext markup langauge and the functions it provides are to be considered a programmatic environment. However, to the question itself, I'm pretty sure that the core MediaWiki software does not offer such a function. What's the reason you don't want to use any extension?

Comment: @Noam don't have access to install extensions.

Comment: @Mattamue I am assuming you does not own the MediaWiki server but hosting it on a platform. Can I ask which platform? Perhaps it does have a relevant extension already installed.